# How to use Apple in app purchase with WKWebView

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, webkit

I have an e-commerce App based on WebKit. I know apple will reject the app because it contains payments and we don't use there in app purchase.
so, my question is: is there any way to integrate in app purchase with the WebKit.
for example, once the user clicks on "buy" button, we may terminate the webView and presenting a view controller with payment details.

Comment: e-commerce? I'm assuming you have physical products... You only have to use in-app purchases for digital products.

Comment: What does "How to use Apple in app purchase with WKWebView" mean?

Comment: @loremipsum yes. i will edit my question. the web site is providing some consulting services.. virtual services. users pay to talk with some professional consultant.  so, is it possible to make an app based on web view without using in app purchase?

Comment: Look at the guidelines, I am not sure if consulting services is one of the excepted categories. It might be since it is more than a digital product but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like You don’t need in app purchase if you are offering consulting services.

> 3.1.3(d) Person-to-Person Services: If your app enables the purchase of real-time person-to-person services between two individuals (for example tutoring students, medical consultations, real estate tours, or fitness training), you may use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments. One-to-few and one-to-many real-time services must use in-app purchase.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#3.1.1